# How to delete rows that contain 0 in the "last column" in a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, terminal

I'm wondering how can I delete rows when the value in the last column is `"0"` in multiple `.tsv` files where the last column number might not be the same for all files. And total number of columns varies hugely in different files.

Precisely I'm looking one-liner in `awk` or `sed`.

This is the first few rows and cols of a `.tsv` file, where the last column is `"0"`, those rows I need to remove. However, the last column number is not the same for all files.

```
$cut -f1-10 temp_13jLiC.bed | awk '{c=0;for(i=4;i<=NF;++i){c+=$i};print $0, "", c}' | head -n 10 | sed 's/ /\t/g' 

chr1    0   100  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    100 200  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    200 300  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    300 400  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    400 500  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    500 600  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    600 700  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    700 800  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    800 900  .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
chr1    900 1000 .  .   .   .   .   .   .       0
```

Comment: You don't need cut, head, sed and a bunch of pipes when you're using awk and you don't need to add yet another pipe to awk or anything else for the issue youre asking about. If you post concise testable sample input (content of the .bed file) and the final expected output so we can help you.

Comment: It seems like the most important part of your question is "where the last column number might not be the same for all files" but you've only shown us 1 input file so we can't adequately test that part of a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do:

```
awk '$NF != 0'
```

Or, since bed is a tab separated format that allows spaces within fields:

```
awk -F'\t' '$NF != 0'
```

`$NF` is auto-magically the last column¹.

If the last column is `0`², then the row will not be printed

---

<sup>¹ As long as the record has at least one column. Otherwise, `NF` would be `0` and `$0` (the `$` operator applied to the number `0`, don't confuse that with variables) is the whole record.</sup>

<sup>² strictly speaking, that's any representation of the number zero recognised by your `awk` implementation which will also include things like `000`, `-0`, `0E+12` but also sometimes depending on the `awk` implementation or the locale or environment `0.00`/`0,00`, `0x0`, `0x0p12`, `1e-500` or `0XFFP-2345`. To only accept a literal `0`, replace with `$NF != "0"`</sup>

Comment: or just `awk '$NF'` if the OP doesn't need to distinguish zero vs empty and it looks like they will always have a number at the end of every line given it's output from `c=0; ... print $0, "", c` so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @EdMorton, with `awk '$NF'` (without a `-F` so with the default field splitting), `$NF` would only be empty for empty records (not even blank records as in that case `NF` would be 0, so `$NF` would be the whole record).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's a good point, I should've put a bit more thought into my comment, thanks for mentioning it. None of it (empty $NF or not, tab-separated or not) really matters in this particular script of course given the input to this script that the OP is outputting from their previous one with `c=0; ... print $0, "", c` guaranteeing that `$NF` is always present and a number in every line and so `awk '$NF'` is all the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's an untested guess since idk what your `.bed` file looks like but this may be what you want, using GNU awk or any other where setting `NF` to a lower value truncates `$0`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>10{exit} NF>10{NF=10} {c=0; for(i=4;i<=NF;++i) c+=$i} c{print $0, "", c}' temp_13jLiC.bed
```

The effect of setting `NF` is undefined behavior in POSIX so if setting NF to 10 doesn't truncate the number of fields to 10 in the awk you're using, there are various alternatives that'd work in any awk including:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>10{exit} {nf=(NF>10 ? 10 : NF); out=""; c=0; for(i=4;i<=nf;++i) {out=out $i OFS; c+=$i}} c{print out, c}' temp_13jLiC.bed
```